# How to correctly format a datetime with Django and Python

Tags: python, django, datetime

I have a model called `Data` in Django and one of the fields is called time_last_updated. It is initialized as follows:

```
time_last_updated=timezone.now()
```

When I query the database (PostgresSQL) manually, the date looks like `2014-02-26 01:42:44.290443+00` which is all fine and as I expected. The problem is that when I take my `Data` object in a python shell, I get this:

```
>>> Data.objects.all[0].time_last_updated    
datetime.datetime(2014, 2, 26, 1, 42, 44, 290443, tzinfo=<UTC>)
```

However, if I immediately try and put this result directly back into the shell as if to create a `datetime` object form it, I get a `SyntaxError` at the `=` right after `tzinfo`.
How is it possible that Django is returning an object with invalid syntax?

Comment: It is just how the value of your datetime field is printed on the console.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. How can it return an object that had a syntax error?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. I mean that it's not supposed to be used for creating datetime objects. It's just a string representation of a `datetime` object. `Data.objects.all[0].time_last_updated` is still of a `datetime` type.

Comment: Do you have timezone support enabled in your settings file? Is pytz installed?

Comment: Ok, so it is simply a string representation of the object... oh. It seems weird because if i take out the tzinfo parameter, and then use that to create an object it works. So i guess I am really asking if there is any way to change the default string representation of the datetime object?

Comment: pytz is indeed installed, and that flag is enabled.

Comment: Yup, you may want to use [strftime](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strftime).

Comment: @ColeCanning: `obj == eval(repr(obj))` is often true (but not always).  See `help(repr)`. And when it is not true; it is customary to use `<...>` in the string representation of an object (`eval()` should raise `SyntaxError` in this case, try `eval(repr(object()))` in the REPL).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In fact, the `datetime` use the representation of the object stored in `tzinfo` when you're printing the `datetime` object in your Python shell.
Django uses its `django.utils.timezone` module to initialize dates and so the `tzinfo` attribute is equal to `django.utils.timezone.utc` (by default, when you haven't specified any timezone).

When you're looking to the `__repr__` of `utc` you can see:

```
>>> from django.utils.timezone import utc
>>> repr(utc)
'<UTC>'
```

Hence the `tzinfo=<UTC>`. It's a string representation, not a real Python value.

Comment: Thanks! I actually do have a default timezone in my settings.py, and its not utc, but thats a different issue. I appreciate the help! I am working on fixing my problem now and I am going to post my solution later.